# Using Quasar q-select with a filter enabled when options is a json object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I cannot find any examples using composition api for this and could use some direction. I have a q-select which passes options as a prop using a axios request. The data is in this form:

```
[{description: "Apple Inc.", displaySymbol: "AAPL"}, {description: "Microsoft", displaySymbol: "MSFT"}]
```

I have about 20000 records in this JSON response. I am able to display it all in a v-select using:

```
          <q-select
          class="grey-7"
          filled
          v-model="addStockSymbol"
          use-input
          input-debounce="0"
          label="Add New Stock Symbol"
          :options="stockTickers"
          option-label="description"
          option-value="displaySymbol"
          @blur="addPosition"
          @filter="filterFn"
          behavior="menu"
        >
          <template v-slot:no-option>
            <q-item>
              <q-item-section class="text-grey">
                No results
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
          </template>
        </q-select>
```

My issue is I do not know how to setup the filter and update function so I can search this. So far I have the code below but the examples on quasar do not use any arrays with objects but rather simple arrays. So I am wondering how do I approach this?

```
<script>
import {watch, ref, defineComponent,onMounted} from 'vue'
import {usePortfolioStore} from '../stores/portfolio-store'
import {storeToRefs} from 'pinia'
import {finnhubAPI} from 'boot/axios'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'UploadPositions',
  components: {
    
  },
    setup () {
      //v-models
      const addStockSymbol = ref('')
      const addShareCount = ref('')
      const stockTickers = ref([])

      const loadData = () => {
        finnhubAPI.get('/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=tedkfjdkfdfd')
        .then((response) => {
          stockTickers.value = response.data
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('API request failed')
        })
      }

      const filterFn = (val, update) => {
        if (val === '') {
          update(() => {
            stockTickers.value = 
          })
          return
        }
      }
      
      update(() => {
        const needle = val.toLowerCase()
        this.options = stringOptions.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1)
      })
      
      //add on mount API request
      onMounted(() => {
        loadData()   
      })

    return {
      addStockSymbol, addShareCount, portfolio, addPosition, deletePosition, 
      loadData, stockTickers, modifyTickerData, filterFn, update
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but options don't have to be a "simple array" they can be an array of objects like this: `:options="[ { label: 'BMW', value: 'car' }, { label: 'Samsung Phone', value: 'phone' } ]"` if you use Array.map() on your data to convert it to an array of this format does that help you at all? https://i.imgur.com/ILFhdCV.png

Comment: @WillD Yea I have an array of objects as shown in my question above. That is what I am trying to use but I cannot figure out how to use the filter with this sort of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to store a complete copy of the response data and keep that around, untouched, so that each time the filter function is called you can filter off of that, looking within its objects for the `label` prop.

When setting up refs:

```
  //v-models
  const addStockSymbol = ref('')
  const addShareCount = ref('')
  const stockTickers = ref([])
  const allResponseData= ref([]) // <-- add this one
```

Then your loadData function:

```
const loadData = () => {
            finnhubAPI.get('/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=cc8ffgiad3iciiq4brf0')
            .then((response) => {
              
             const responseData = response.data.map((item) => ({label: item.description, value: item.displaySymbol}));
             allResponseData.value = [...responseData];
             stockTickers.value = [...responseData];
            })
            .catch(() => {
              console.log('API request failed')
            })
          }
```

Then in your filter function:

```
const filterFn =  (val, update, abort) => {
        update(() => {
          const needle = val.toLowerCase()
          stockTickers.value = allResponseData.value.filter(option => {
           return option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1
          })
        })
      }
```

See it in action:

```js
const { ref } = Vue

const stringOptions = [
  {label: 'Google', value: "goog"}, {label:'Facebook',value:'fb'}, {label:'Twitter', value: "twit"},{label: 'Apple', value: 'App'}]

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    const options = ref(stringOptions)

    return {
      model: ref(null),
      options,

      filterFn (val, update, abort) {
        update(() => {
          const needle = val.toLowerCase()
          options.value = stringOptions.filter(option => {
           return option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.7.7/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.7.7/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
<!--
  Forked from:
  https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#example--basic-filtering
-->
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md row">
      <q-select
        filled
        v-model="model"
        use-input
        hide-selected
        fill-input
        input-debounce="0"
        :options="options"
        @filter="filterFn"
        hint="Basic filtering"
        style="width: 250px; padding-bottom: 32px"
      >
        <template v-slot:no-option>
          <q-item>
            <q-item-section class="text-grey">
              No results
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
        </template>
      </q-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Any reason you prefer to map it to value and label rather than just using the option-value and option-label properties?

Comment: No reason,  if it works just as well with the original propnames then go for it, it would save a little bit of compute.

Comment: One last question to perfect this q-select. I have about 20000 stocks showing in this giant drop down that takes up the entire screen. Can you limit how many are visible and let scroll take care of the rest?

Comment: Maybe look into the "virtual scroll" feature of the select element.